# Take random ids, then store those random ids into the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I'm working on a code snippet that essentially takes out 35 random ids from the table List.

What I would like to do to find the ids that got randomly generated, store them into a database called Status.

The purpose is to avoid duplication the next time I get a new 35 random ids from the List. So I never get the same random id twice.

Here's what I've tried, but been unsuccessful to get working.

```
@schedule = current_user.schedules.new
 if @schedule.save
@user = User.find(params[:id])
 Resque.enqueue(ScheduleTweets, @user.token)
 @schedule.update_attribute(:trial, true)
 flash[:notice] = "success"
 redirect_to :back
else
 flash[:alert] = "Try again."
 redirect_to :back
end
```

and the worker:

```
def self.perform(user_token)
list = List.first(6)
@status = list.statuses.create
list.each do |list|
  Status.create(list_id: "#{list}")
  if list.avatar.present?
    client.create_update(body: {text: "#{list.text}", profile_ids: profile_ids, media: { 'thumbnail' => 'http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/85/kids/128/thumbnail.png', 'photo' => 'http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/85/kids/128/thumbnail.png' } })
  end
end
```

end

however the `Status.create(list_id: #list)` doesn't work. 
Does anybody have any idea what is going on, and how I can make the list_ids get saved successfully to Status?

It's also associated:
list has many statuses, and status belongs to list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code is wrong:

```
Status.create(list_id: "#{list}") # WRONG
```

In your case the `list` variable is a `List` instance. And you're passing its string version to `list_id` which expects an integer.

Do this:

```
Status.create(list_id: list.id)
```

Or this:

```
list.statuses.create
```

I think the following will also work:

```
Status.create(list: list)
```